# free() freezing in visual studio C

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have a problem with the function free() in visual studio. When I call the function free() to free  the memory that I used the visual studio console freezes. I tried to compile the same code  with gcc compilator and it works just fine.

Here is a sample from my code (the language is C ):

function xorshift32:

```
  unsigned int* xorshift32(int size, int seed);
{
    unsigned int r, k;
    r = (unsigned int) seed;
    unsigned int* v = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
    v[0] = seed;
    for(k = 1; k<=size;k++)
{
        r = r ^ r << 13; 
        r = r ^ r >> 17;
        r = r ^ r << 5;
        v[k] = (unsigned int) r;
}
    return v;
}
```

the call of the function and free function:

```
    unsigned int *random_sequence;
    random_sequence = xorshift32(rand_size, seed);
    free(random_sequence);
```

Comment: the code of the function would be a plus to know if it allocates something or not...

Comment: Are we supposed to *guess* what nefarious things are going on inside of `xorshift32` ?

Comment: Does `xorshift32` actually allocate memory with `malloc()`?

Comment: Sorry, I added the function code to my quesiton

Comment: you don't need to cast values. Destination types are already what you want. `v[k] = (unsigned int) r;` => `v[k] = r;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(k = 1; k<=size;k++)
```

The memory you allocated is valid until index `size - 1`, but `k` can go up to `size`; so when writing to `v{size]` you trigger a memory corruption.

What follows is *undefined behaviour*, and it shows when freeing the buffer (but it could have done something else, even if in those cases, either it crashes right at the line where you're overwriting the memory, or at the next memory operation `free` or `malloc`, because of memory list corruption.)

Personally I tend to avoid conditions with an inferior or equal test (`k<=size;`) in `for` loops because one-off errors are easy. It's better to compute a variable called `size_plus_one` and use `k < size_plus_one`.

Alloc one more element to fix this:

```
unsigned int* v = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: That was it, now it works. Thanks. I thought that was something with the compiler since in visual-c++ compiler it freezes and in gcc compiler it works.

Comment: undefined behaviour, as I said. The compiler is generally bug-free for simple uses like that.

Comment: @MihaiM another option is to change your loop to `for(k = 0; k<size;k++)`, and in fact if you want `size` items as the variable name suggests, I suspect this is what you want. Array indices are 0-based in C, might as well get used to it. An array with `size` elements is indexed from 0 to `size-1`. Allocating an extra space and looping from 1 to `<= arraySize` is not commonly done.

Comment: @yano I use v[0] to store my seed for the  pseudorandom numbers

Comment: @MihaiM Ahhh, right you are. My apologies, I didn't look carefully.

Comment: @yano: OP puts the seed in the array first. Then the elements. So there's the size of the elements, plus one. Else my answer would be wrong.